# Grouping strings lexicographically (python)

Tags: python, string, bucket, data-partitioning

I have N strings that I want to divide lexicographic into M even-sized buckets (+/- 1 string). Also, N>>M.

The direct way would be to sort all the strings and split the resulting list into the M buckets.

I would like to instead approximate this by routing each string as it is created to a bucket, before the full list is available.

Is there a fast and pythonic way to assign strings to buckets? I'm essentially looking for a string-equivalent of the integer modulo operator. Perhaps a hash that preserves lexicographic order? Is that even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sort by first two chars of a string, or something of this sort.

Let's say that `M=100`, so you should divide the characters into `sqrt(M)` regions, and each should point to another `sqrt(M)` regions, then for each string you get, you can compare the first char to decide which region to direct the string to and again for the second char, something like a tree with buckets as leaves and comparisons as nodes.

Answer (score 0):

A hash by definition doesn't preserve any order.

And I don't think there is any pythonic way to do this.

You could just create dictionaries (which are basically hashing functions) and keep adding a string to each round-robin style, but it wouldn't preserve any order.